# RedirectMatch 301 for just html file

Tags: mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I need to do a mass 301 Redirect for all pages ending with .html for my site. I am looking to move all the old .html files to a sub-folder ir.

```
RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\.html$ http://www.domain.com/folder/$1.html
```

When I add this and refresh the browser I get a ton of folder/folder/folder now after the url ie

domain.com/folder//folder/folder/folder.....

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Thanks if you can help

Comment: Give a concrete example of a source URL you're redirecting from and where would you like it to be redirected.

Comment: OK i I was to give a better example a normal 301 would be
RedirectMatch 301 file.html http://www.domain.com/folder/file.html

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that 'folder/foo.html' also matches the condition of the RedirectMatch and folder is appended again (and again, and again ...)

Therefore you probably need something like this (untested):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ /folder/$1.html [R=301,L]
```

The RewriteCond should check that the URI doesn't start with /folder and only if this condition is met, the RewriteRule will be checked.

Unfortunately I haven't any Apache installation available at the moment for testing such things, so you will probably have to try it on your own. But I hope you got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

If your old html files are in the root, I would suggest the following:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^([^/]+)\.html$ http://www.domain.com/folder/$1.html
```